# How to use ipv6 with Vagrant and VirtualBox?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ipv6, vagrant

I have a Vagrant setup running Ubuntu in VirtualBox. I'm trying to create a public virtual network interface that I can access from the host. I have had no problem doing this with ipv4. Using ipv6 I set the interface up like:

```
guest$ ip link add derpcraft link eth1 type macvlan mode bridge;    
guest$ ip -6 addr add fdfe:dcba:9876:ffff::/64 dev derpcraft
guest$ ip link set derpcraft up
```

The interface looks like:

```
        derpcraft Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 26:22:d5:54:95:00  
                  inet6 addr: fe80::2422:d5ff:fe54:9500/64 Scope:Link
                  inet6 addr: fdfe:dcba:9876:ffff::/64 Scope:Global
                  UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
                  RX packets:264 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                  TX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                  collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
                  RX bytes:52989 (52.9 KB)  TX bytes:2040 (2.0 KB)
```

From the host machine I can't seem to ping this either address on the interface.

```
host$ ping6 fe80::2422:d5ff:fe54:9500
ping6: UDP connect: No route to host
host$ ping6 fe80::2422:d5ff:fe54:9500%::1
ping6: UDP connect: No route to host
host$ ping6 fdfe:dcba:9876:ffff::
ping6: UDP connect: No route to host
host$ ping6 fdfe:dcba:9876:ffff::%::1
ping6: UDP connect: No route to host
```

I think I may need to configure Vagrant or VirtualBox to accept ipv6 connections.

Another point. My current ISP is not ipv6 friendly yet. I don't suspect that has anything to do with it because this should all be a local request.

Update: For good measure I gave the interface an ipv4 address like:

```
guest$ ip address add 192.168.33.11/24 broadcast 192.168.33.255 dev derpcraft
guest$ ifconfig
derpcraft Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 26:22:d5:54:95:00  
          inet addr:192.168.33.11  Bcast:192.168.33.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2422:d5ff:fe54:9500/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fdfe:dcba:9876:ffff::/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1736 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:418224 (418.2 KB)  TX bytes:2040 (2.0 KB)
```

And I can ping that form the host no problem:

```
host$ ping 192.168.33.11
PING 192.168.33.11 (192.168.33.11): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.33.11: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.497 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.33.11: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.426 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.33.11: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.388 ms
^C
--- 192.168.33.11 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.388/0.437/0.497/0.045 ms
```

Update: The host interface looks like:

```
host$ ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 04:0c:ce:e4:1f:be 
    inet6 fe80::60c:ceff:fee4:1fbe%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet 192.168.1.72 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    media: autoselect
    status: active
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 06:0c:ce:e4:1f:be 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
vboxnet0: flags=8842<BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 
vboxnet1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:01 
    inet 192.168.33.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.33.255
```

Which shows neither of the VirtualBox interfaces have inet6, and this is probably the issue, but i'm not sure how to enable it.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is VirtualBox on a FreeBSD host?

Comment: this is a OSX host

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like using vagrants `public_network` option will bridge the virtualbox interface to the host interface piggy backing IPV6